# Use reduce to sum attributes of objects in array

Tags: ruby, collect

I have a class called `Food`; it's a very simple class, it just has name, price, and Kcal. I created three kinds of `Food`:

```
@Food1 = Food.new("Pear", 12, 120)
@Food2 = Food.new("Apple", 15, 100)
@Food3 = Food.new("Banana", 20, 200)
```

Then I created an array of foods called `Menu`:

```
@Menu = [@Food1, @Food2, @Food3]
```

I need to sum all the `prices` with the `reduce` method, and store them in `@Food1`. I have implemented the `+` method for the `food` class:

```
def + (other)
    @price + other.price
end
```

And I am trying to do:

```
@Food1 = @Menu.reduce(:+)
```

But it does not work. Do you have some idea how I can reach this?

Comment: Ruby convention holds that variables and method names should be all lower-case. That is `@food1` and `@menu` in this case.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error?

Comment: Show other relevant parts of you code. Without defining the `initialize` method, your code won't work. Without having an accessor method, your code won't work.

Comment: @MatthewWhite: In the case of *reduce*, you do not need a Proc object to pass as argument. See the docs: Just a symbol of the method to be applied is sufficient. In this case, the first element of the collection is used as the initial value for the memo object, and the method denoted by the symbol is applied. For example, `[3,5].reduce(:+)` evaluates to 8. You **can** use a *Proc* and write `[3,5].reduce(&:+)`, but you don't have to.

Comment: @user1934428, thanks for the comment, you're right, I never knew that about `#reduce`!

Comment: "does not work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to write it as follows.

```
class Food
  attr_reader :price
  def initialize(name, price, kcal)
    @name, @price, @kcal = name, price, kcal
  end
end

food1 = Food.new("Pear",   12, 120)
food2 = Food.new("Apple",  15, 100)
food3 = Food.new("Banana", 20, 200)
menu = [food1, food2, food3]`enter code here`

menu.reduce(0) { |t,food| t+food.price }
  #=> 47
```

or (for Ruby v2.4+)

```
menu.sum { |food| food.price }
```

Notice that I didn't define `food1`, `food2`, `food3` or `menu` as instance variables. There may be a reason for doing so, but not just to obtain the sum of the prices.

`Food.new.price` is an integer, for which [Integer#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-2B) is of course defined, so there is no particular reason to define and instance method `+` on the class.

Suppose you did add an instance method `:+` to the class:

```
def +(other)
  price + other.price
end
```

This would allow you to write

```
food1 + food2
  #=> 27
```

(though it is not intuitive that prices are being summed). However, you cannot write

```
food1 + food2 + food3
```

because `food1 + food2` is first executed, returning `27`, then an attempt is made to execute

```
27 + food3
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
27.+(food3)
```

Here `:+` is an Integer method, which does not accept `food3` as an argument and therefore raises an exception.

Comment: … which is why you should always implement `coerce` if you want your objects to behave like numbers.